# PHP error with too many IF statements, need second view

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

Im lost in `if`, `else` statments and cant figure out right syntax with obviously simple problem.

i have 3 situations, `code` which i looking for is saved in DTB, OR hardcoded and code start  `CODE_1-`OR no `code` at all.

first defined variable `$code`

```
$code = Discount::where('code',$discount_code)
```

1] lets check if variable `$code` is in database or return 0

```
if (!is_null($code) !== false){
   $response['discount'] = $code->discount;
   } else {
     $response['valid'] = false;
     $response['discount'] = 0;
```

2] variable isnt in DTB but is hardcoded `CODE_1-` this type of codes always start at `CODE_1-` so function `strpos` can help

and there start my problem, `code` isnt in datebase

```
if (is_null($code) = (strpos($discount_code, 'CODE-')) {
    $response['valid'] = true;
    $response['discount'] = 50;
```

3] `Code` isnt hardoced or saved in databese

```
?
```

can be all this conditions merged together ?

UPDATE 1

how to put condition to this line `if (strpos($discount_code, 'CODE-') !== false) {`

=> `IF $code = null than strpos(...`

```
        if (!is_null($code) !== false) {
            $referal_uid = $this->usersRepo->getIdByHash($discount_code);
            $userExists = User::find($referal_uid);
            $different_user = ($referal_uid !== Auth::id() ? true : false);
                if ($userExists && $different_user)
                {
                    $response['valid'] = true;
                    $response['discount'] = $code->discount;
                    $response['referal'] = $userExists->email;

                } else {
                    $response['valid'] = false;
                    $response['discount'] = 0;
                    $response['referal'] = '';

                }

                if (strpos($discount_code, 'CODE-') !== false) {
                    $referal_uid = $this->usersRepo->getIdByHash($discount_code);
                    $userExists = User::find($referal_uid);
                    $different_user = ($referal_uid !== Auth::id() ? true : false);
                    if ($userExists && $different_user)
                    {
                        $response['valid'] = true;
                        $response['discount'] = 5;
                        $response['referal'] = $userExists->email;
                    }
                    return $response;
                }
                
                return $response;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `is_null`?

Comment: my adea how first looking in database, becosue code can be outside database too, maybe im not right

Comment: If you try like this, what do you get ? ```code = Discount::where('code',$discount_code)->first();``` ```dd($code);```

Comment: @EncangCutbray Debugbar::info($code) returns
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 58
    "subscription" => "quarter"
    "used_by" => 11422
    "student" => "N"
    "discount" => 89.0
    "expiry" => "2020-10-06 00:00:00"
    "taken" => "R"
    "code" => "CODE-dLZQpa"
    "created_at" => "2020-09-26 09:47:36"
    "updated_at" => "2020-09-26 09:47:36"
  ]